# Question about Batmobile 76139 build

Tags: building, instructions

What's the purpose of the hinge plates in Step 133?

[image: Step 133 of instructions]

I ask because it got in the way when installing the side sections in Steps 222 and 231. I simply pushed it out of the way and everything was OK. However, I cannot see what it is used for in subsequent steps. I am worried I may have missed something and have to go back.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell from the instructions alone (available at [this 197MiB PDF from LEGO support](https://www.lego.com/cdn/product-assets/product.bi.core.pdf/6362926.pdf)), the purpose of those particular hinge plates is to serve as **bottom** support of the 1x12 technic bricks introduced in step 214 (and its symmetrical counterpart in 223). Let me try to illustrate:

[image: step 214]

So when the subassembly from steps 214-221 is attached, things should look like...

[image: Step 222]

(Idem for the symmetrical counterpart)

In other words: the 1x12 beam should be supported by *three* hinge plates: two at the top, and one at the bottom. The bottom one is introduced in step 133.

Comment: Aha - I now see - indeed, as I am not much further on, I could make that work ! It wasn't obvious to me at first as the element was quite secure on just two. Also, really tricky to get the lower one in exactly the right position for it to click on. I have managed it however - thanks so much Ivan !